# QtMultimedia Metadata returns undefined

Tags: qt, qml

Whenever I try to access the metadata right after I load an audio file, it always returned undefined. However, if I load the audio file after the whole qml file has been loaded, it grabs the metadata. Clearly, this has something to do with the loading of components. My question now is how to properly load the audio file to the MediaPlayer on load that allows me to get the metadata and add it to a ListView. All media control works fine. It's just the metadata is not playing nice.

manually loading the audio file which returns undefined value

```
Component.onCompleted: {
        playLogic.myPlayer.source = Qt.resolvedUrl("file://"+playLogic.items.get(0,"filePath"));
        console.log(playLogic.myPlayer.metaData.contributingArtist);
}
```

loading the files in FolderListModel

```
Item{
      id:playLogic
      property FolderListModel items: FolderListModel {
           folder: "file://"+musicPath
           nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
      }
}
```

text element that displays the metadata when play is pressed

```
Text {
      id: songTitle
      text: playLogic.myPlayer.metaData.title ? playLogic.myPlayer.metaData.title : ""
      font.pointSize: 14
      color: "white"
      anchors.top: parent.bottom
}
Text {
     id: songArtist
     text: playLogic.myPlayer.metaData.contributingArtist ? playLogic.myPlayer.metaData.contributingArtist: "no metadata"
     font.pointSize: 12
     color: "white"
     anchors.top: songTitle.bottom
}
```